# Advanced MySQL search with Sphinx

Tags: php, mysql, search, sphinx

I've been through a lot of dead ends trying to improve the speed of a search engine and I finally came to a decision to move on to Sphinx (for better or worse). So our website is an online shop based on custom built MVC framework.

When an user searches, for let's say "**whey protein**", we are offering him results for these keywords as well as filtered categories and properties.

So let's say a product named "**100% whey protein**" is in a category "Proteins", this category has assigned properties:

- Taste - Chocolate, Vanilla, Strawberry
- Pack size - 1kg, 2kg, 5kg
- Color - Blue, Red, White, Black

The product "**100% whey protein**" has these values:

- Taste - Chocolate, Strawberry
- Pack size - 2kg, 5kg
- Color - Red

When user searches for a phrase "**whey protein**" we're showing him all the products that contain that phrase, as well we filter our categories to show only those who contain products with that phrase and our properties which have products with the phrase. Shown example you can look on [this link](http://www.gofit.bg/store?search=whey%20protein) (you can use Google translate, because the website is in bulgarian).

So this is my Sphinx config file.

```
source content {

    sql_query_pre           =   SET NAMES utf8
    sql_query               = \
                            SELECT p.*, p.product_id, \
                            m.man_name, m.man_image_location, m.man_seo_url, pcr.ctg_id, \
                            gal.image_filelocation, pir.item_id, pav.atr_id \
                            from 3w_products p \
                            INNER JOIN 3w_products_gallery gal ON gal.product_id = p.product_id AND (gal.show_order = 1 OR gal.show_order = NULL)\
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN 3w_manufacturers m ON m.man_id = p.man_id \
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN 3w_products_cat_rel pcr ON pcr.product_id = p.product_id \
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN 3w_product_item_rel pir ON pir.product_id = p.product_id \
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN 3w_product_attribute_values pav ON pav.product_id = p.product_id \
                            ;
    #attribute declaration  
    sql_attr_uint           = product_id
    sql_attr_uint           = man_id
    sql_attr_uint           = product_notinstock
    sql_field_string        = product_name
    sql_field_string        = man_name
    sql_field_string        = product_code
    sql_field_string        = product_seo_url
    sql_field_string        = image_filelocation
    sql_field_string        = product_intro_plain
    sql_field_string        = product_second_name
    sql_field_string        = product_price
    sql_field_string        = product_price_promo
    sql_field_string        = product_promo_expire_date
    sql_field_string        = product_views
    sql_field_string        = product_rating
    sql_field_string        = product_date_added
    sql_field_string        = product_price_returned
    sql_field_string        = man_image_location
    sql_field_string        = man_seo_url


    sql_attr_uint          = product_exquisite
    sql_attr_uint          = product_votes
    sql_attr_uint          = product_returned


    sql_attr_multi          = uint item_id from field; items
    sql_attr_multi          = uint atr_id from field; attributes
    sql_attr_multi          = uint ctg_id from field; categories
}
```

And the PHP code:

```
        require_once("extensions/libs/sphinx/sphinxapi.php");
        if ($params['order']) {
            switch ($params['order']) {
                case 'newest':
                    $order = 'product_notinstock ASC, product_id DESC';
                    break;
                case 'priceup':
                    $order = 'product_notinstock ASC, p.product_price_sell ASC';
                    break;
                case 'pricedown':
                    $order = 'product_notinstock ASC, p.product_price_sell DESC';
                    break;
                case 'views':
                    $order = 'product_notinstock ASC, product_views DESC';
                    break;
                case 'promoted':
                    $order = 'product_notinstock ASC, p.product_price_promo DESC';
                    break;
                case 'exquisite':
                    if (!$params['search']) {
                        $order = 'p.product_notinstock ASC, p.product_exquisite DESC, p.product_views DESC';
                        break;
                    } else {
                        $order = "product_notinstock ASC, @weight DESC, product_views DESC ";  
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    $order = "product_notinstock ASC, @weight DESC, product_views DESC "; 
                    break;
            }
        }

        $phrase = $params['search'];
        $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;

        $client = new SphinxClient();
        $client->SetLimits($params['offset'], $params['limit']);
        $client->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, $order);
        $client->SetRankingMode(SPH_RANK_SPH04);
        $client->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED);

        $client->SetFieldWeights(array('product_code'=>30, 'product_name'=>15, 'product_meta_data'=>2));
        if($params['returned']) $client->setFilter('product_returned', array($params['returned']));
        if($params['man_id']) $client->setFilter('man_id', array($params['man_id']));
        if($params['ctg_id']) $client->setFilter('ctg_id', array($params['ctg_id']));
        if($params['properties']) 
            foreach($params['properties'] as $prop_id => $prop) $client->setFilter('item_id', array_keys($prop['items']));
        if($params['attribute']) $client->setFilter('atr_id', array($params['attribute']['atr_id']));

        $phrase = str_replace(" - ", "-", $phrase);
        $query = '@product_name ('.$phrase.') | @product_meta_data ('.$phrase.') | @product_code ('.$phrase.')';
        $res = $client->Query($query, 'products');
        $products = array();
        foreach($res['matches'] as $id => $product) {
            $product['attrs']['product_id'] = $id;
            $products[] = $product['attrs'];
        }
        $return['result'] = $products;
        $return['finded'] = $res['total_found'];

        return $return;
```

This, however returns proper results. But I need to migrate some other queries to Sphinx, to improve the speed even more.

Query 1 - Categories:

```
SELECT c.ctg_id, c.ctg_parent_id, c.ctg_name, 
c.ctg_seo_url, count(distinct pcr.product_id) products 
FROM 3w_product_categories c 
LEFT JOIN 3w_products_cat_rel pcr ON pcr.ctg_id = c.ctg_id 
LEFT JOIN 3w_products p ON p.product_id = pcr.product_id 
WHERE ( MATCH (p.product_code,p.product_meta_data) 
AGAINST ('+whey* +protein*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
GROUP BY c.ctg_id ORDER BY c.ctg_name
```

Query 2 - Manufactures:

```
SELECT m.man_id, m.man_name, 
m.man_seo_url, count(distinct p.product_id) products 
FROM 3w_manufacturers m 
INNER JOIN 3w_products p ON p.man_id = m.man_id 
WHERE ( MATCH (p.product_code,p.product_meta_data) 
AGAINST ('+whey* +protein*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
GROUP BY m.man_id ORDER BY m.man_name ASC
```

Query 3 - Properties (and their items):

```
SELECT pi.item_id, pi.item_name, pi.item_slug, pp.prop_id, 
pp.prop_name, pp.prop_slug, count(distinct pir.product_id) products 
FROM 3w_property_items pi 
LEFT JOIN 3w_product_item_rel pir ON pir.item_id = pi.item_id 
INNER JOIN 3w_products p ON p.product_id = pir.product_id 
LEFT JOIN 3w_properties pp ON pp.prop_id = pi.prop_id 
WHERE ( MATCH (p.product_code,p.product_meta_data) 
AGAINST ('+whey* +protein*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) 
ORDER BY pp.prop_name ASC, pi.item_name ASC
```

I have Query 4 whichs is for product's attributes, but it's some kind of equivalent to Query 3.

So my question is - how to implement all these queries in the Sphinx index? And as I type another one comes in my head - what happens when an administrator inserts/edits a product? How it's the Sphinx index updated? Cron every night?

I don't mind rewriting all the search engine, as I know it's not perfectly organized.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Consider running EXPLAIN EXTENDED followed by SHOW WARNINGS for each of those queries, and pasting the results here.

Comment: To be honest, this question seems a bit lazyweb, and rather long for anyone to comprehend. You seem to figured how to convert one query to sphinx, do the same again for others; rather than just asking people to 'write the code' for you. Finally the question about updates, should be seperate (although pretty if you look for some tutorials online, will be able to answer yourself)